# How to add values to already existing ones in a matrix using 'for' loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I wrote a piece of code in MATLAB which basically assigns values from matrix 'Ke' (8x8, just constants) to matrix 'KG' which is initially filled with zeros. Numbers of rows and columns to which values should be assigned are given by the array nEN, which varies in another loop but is alway an array of 4 numbers.

```
KG=[];
 for t=1:Nw
    for i=1:Nh
    eN=Am(t:t+1,i:i+1)
    nEN=reshape(eN',1,[])
      for i1=1:4
         for i2=1:4
         KG((2*(nEN(i1))-1),(2*(nEN(i2))-1))=Ke(((2*i1)-1),((2*i2)-1));
         KG((2*(nEN(i1))-1),(2*(nEN(i2))))=Ke((2*i1-1),(2*i2));
         KG((2*(nEN(i1))),(2*(nEN(i2))-1))=Ke((2*i1),(2*i2-1));
         KG((2*(nEN(i1))),(2*(nEN(i2))))=Ke((2*i1),(2*i2));
         end
      end
    end
 end 
 KG
```

The thing is sometimes nEN can have the same values as those obtained in the previous iteration, and so my loop rewrites the values which have been already present in 'KG', but I want them to be added together instead. How can I do that?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accumulate values in `KG` with:

```
KG((2*(nEN(i1))-1),(2*(nEN(i2))-1)) = KG((2*(nEN(i1))-1),(2*(nEN(i2))-1)) + Ke(((2*i1)-1),((2*i2)-1));
KG((2*(nEN(i1))-1),(2*(nEN(i2)))) = KG((2*(nEN(i1))-1),(2*(nEN(i2)))) + Ke((2*i1-1),(2*i2));
KG((2*(nEN(i1))),(2*(nEN(i2))-1)) = KG((2*(nEN(i1))),(2*(nEN(i2))-1)) + Ke((2*i1),(2*i2-1));
KG((2*(nEN(i1))),(2*(nEN(i2)))) = KG((2*(nEN(i1))),(2*(nEN(i2)))) + Ke((2*i1),(2*i2));
```

Comment: That gives: 

??? Attempted to access KG(1,1); index out of bounds because size(KG)=[0,0].

Error in ==> syscalc at 106
          KG((2*(nEN(i1))-1),(2*(nEN(i2))-1)) = KG((2*(nEN(i1))-1),(2*(nEN(i2))-1)) +
          Ke(((2*i1)-1),((2*i2)-1));

Comment: That means `KG` array isn't initialized as it should be before iterating through those loops. You should place `KG = zeros(YSIZE, XSIZE);` instead of `KG = []`. It is a good practice *not to grow matrices in loops* in Matlab, but specify their dimensions explicitly. If you don't know exact dimensions for the matrix beforehand, specify greater values, and then trim matrix when you're done with calculations with `KG = KG(YMIN:YMAX, YMIN:YMAX);`.

Comment: I've filled it with zeros before the loop and it worked, THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I knew it's got to be something stupidly easy